# How to validate two check boxes and make sure that at least one is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, checkvalidity

I have two check boxes in my form, all other form fields use HTML attribute required so I can run validation on submit. This is little different since I have two check box input fields and I have to require at least one to be checked. Here is an example:

```js
$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitFrm);
function submitFrm(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
    var $checkbox = $('.account-type');

    $checkbox.on('change', function(){
        var checked = false;
  
        $checkbox.each(function(){
           checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked')
        });
  
        $checkbox.prop('required', !checked)
    });

    console.log('Submit form.')
}
```

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
    content: " *";
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="account"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="user">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required class="account-type"> <span class="label label-default">User</span>
      </label>
      <label for="staff">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required class="account-type"> <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </div> 
</form>
```

Example above throws an error `isUser.checkValidity()` is not a function. Is there a way to run validity on checkbox and make at least one of the two required/checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$("#frm_isuser").is(":checked")` will return a bool that shows if `$("#frm_isuser")` is checked or not.

And `checkValidity()` is a DOM methods, so you should use `document.getElementById("frm_isuser").checkValidity()` or `$("#frm_isuser")[0].checkValidity()`.

Edit: If one of the both checkboxes is checked, then set `required` attributes to `false` to both of them. If none of them is checked, set `required` to `true`.

```js
$('.frm-Submit').on('submit', submitFrm);

var $checkbox = $('.custom-class')

$checkbox.on('change', function(){
  var checked = false;
  
  $checkbox.each(function(){
    checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked')
  })
  
  $checkbox.prop('required', !checked)
})

function submitFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.
  
  console.log('Submit form.')
}
```

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="account"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="user">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account" required class="custom-class"> <span class="label label-default">User</span>
      </label>
      <label for="staff">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account" required class="custom-class"> <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
      <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I do not see HTML5 validation message if I click submit and both check boxes are unchecked.

Comment: Cause you didn't add `required` attribute to the checkboxes. Now I update the snippet.

Comment: Again, I do not want to require both of them, I only need one at least to be checked. So either User or Staff has to be checked.

Comment: Please check my snippet above, I have used the same code but still both check boxes are required.

Comment: You forgot to replace `$('.custom-class')` with `$('.account-type')`

Comment: I have changed the class and still the same.

Comment: You have to take the change event outside the `submitFrm` function, or it will check if is required first. So take out the change event and it would be triggered when checked or unchecked the checkboxes.

Comment: I have one more question. So if only User check box is checked then I will show form fields for user account. Staff form fields will be hidden. When I populate all required fields for user I still can't submit the form because hidden fields that are required have to bee filled in. How to prevent those hidden fields to be included in validation?

Comment: Also I do not think that you need this `checked = checked || $(this).is(':checked')` that can be replaced with `checked = $(this).is(':checked')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169627/discussion-between-hikarunomemory-and-espresso-coffee).

Comment: I implemented this solution and got it to work, but would like to configure the alert so that it doesn't point to the first of the two checkboxes.

Comment: This hack works well. I was hoping to overwrite each checkbox's `checkValidity()` function, but the browser disregards it. I also tried to modify directly the `el.validity.valid` value but since it is "live" it won't take the value.

Answer (score 2):

add like this,

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('required', true);
 $('[type="checkbox"]').filter('[required]').change(function(){
  $('[type="checkbox"]').prop('required', ($(this).is(':checked')) ? false : true);
 })
 $('.frm-Submit').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.  
        if($('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0){   
            console.log('Submit form.')
        }else{
   $(this).closest('form').get(0).checkValidity();
  }
    });
 
});
```

```html
<script language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form name="frmSave" id="frmSave" class="frm-Submit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label" for="account"><span class="label label-primary">Account Type:</span></label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label for="user">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isuser" id="frm_isuser" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#user-account"> <span class="label label-default">User</span>
      </label>
      <label for="staff">
         <input type="checkbox" name="frm_isstaff" id="frm_isstaff" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#staff-account"> <span class="label label-info">Staff</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <button type="submit" name="frm_submit" id="frm_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
     </div>
   </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: I need HTML5 validation message if neither of check boxes are checked.

Comment: @espresso_coffee, check now, i have updated the answer

Comment: I still have the problem where both check boxes are required. Not sure why... you can check my snippet above.

Comment: At least one check box has to be checked.

Comment: yeah, my answer is working like as you are requesting.... run the code snippet and check, i have updated

Comment: Yep, I have tested and works fine form me. All I had to do is move the function out of my actual form submit function.

Comment: i didn't get you pal. could you please give me more clarfication

Comment: Submit function from your code above I have moved out. It's not inside the function that sets/checks checkbox required attribute. Does that make sense?

Comment: without adding `required` form for the form, you can't check `checkValidity`. it will only work if `required` exist in your element. if you want to remove that, you should mention required for your checkboxes in html code

Answer (score 1):

`.is(":checked")` already returns a `boolean`...there is no `.checkValidity()` method. Just do:

```
if (isUser || isStaff) {
  //...code here if at least one is true
}
```

---

Update:

The requirement and validation that you need in this case are essentially two separate sets of logic.

[Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) runs on a per input basis so you have to check multiple inputs yourself.

You have the option of swapping the value of the `required` parameter by listening for events on each checkbox...but since they seem to have different `data-target`, I assume the better solution would probably be just using the select form type.

Comment: I would like to show HTML5 validation message if neither of check boxes are checked.

Comment: Updated my response with more of an explanation on how `checkValidity` works but you can check @Hikarunomemory answer on how swapping `required` can get you your desired result.